# Jenkins IRC plugin - how to disable logging?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I'm using `Jenkins 1.651` with the `IRC Plugin 2.27` and
`instant-messaging plugin 1.35`.

I've noticed that the IRC plugin logs a lot of INFO level messages to the Jenkins log (GUI and on-disk). I'd like to configure logging for this plugin, or disable logging for the plugin entirely.

I've tried adding a new log recorder for the logger `hudson.plugins.ircbot`, but the plugin still logged to the general Jenkins log. Any pointers?

Comment: See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this tweet:
https://twitter.com/russss/status/806560486166822915

> (You can fix by changing the level of org.pircbotx.InputParser to WARNING at /log/levels in the web interface. Thanks, pircbot...)

I can confirm this works, but the config doesn't seem to stick after you restart Jenkins. If anyone knows where to capture this to make it permanent, that would be great!

Edit: so not ideal, in so far as it knocks *all* Jenkins logging back to the level of WARNING or higher (no more INFO messages) but this is a permanent fix to the problem you can capture in code and config:

Add the following to JAVA_ARGS for Jenkins (we typically do this in /etc/default/jenkins) :

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/jenkins/logging.properties
```

Then *create* the file /var/lib/jenkins/logging.properties, containing the following:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= WARNING
```

No more IRC messages in the Jenkins log!

This answer actually provided by my colleague, [mig5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943309/mig5)

Comment: Thank you! Not an ideal solution indeed, but it *is* a solution. We ended up using email notification instead - no more public shaming :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46099 that asks for addressing this issue in a persistent way.